# Permission denied to read data from Firebase Realtime Database after applying rules at Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following DB structure, which is used by the app:

```
app_name
|
|-settings
  |
  |-prod
  | |
  | |-version: "abc"
  |
  |-test
    |
    |-version: "def"
```

I decided to add rules to allow read data only from `prod` and `test` nodes. For this purpose I added the rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "settings" : {
      "prod" : {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false
      },
      "test" : {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute queries in the playground everything works ok. But when I run the app on a real Android device I catch the exception that `Permission Denied` in the `onCancelled` callback method. Maybe you can help me to understand what can cause such a problem?

Here's the way how I read data from DB:

```
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()        
    database.reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val buildType = if (BuildConfig.IS_PROD) "prod" else "test"
                Timber.d("Database $snapshot")
                if (snapshot.child("settings").child(buildType).exists()) {
                    val settings =
                        snapshot.child("settings").child(buildType).getValue(Any::class.java)!!
                    val json = Gson().toJson(settings)
                    val settingsDTO =
                        Gson().fromJson(json, FirebaseSettings::class.java)
                    tasks.setResult(settingsDTO)
                    Timber.d("Database 1 $settingsDTO")
                    database.reference.removeEventListener(this)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Timber.d("Database $error")
                tasks.setException(Exception(error.message))
            }
        })
```

When I set the rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

everything works allright. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: How is `database` object defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()        
database.reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
```

Means you are reading from the root of the database. So Firebase evaluates the security rules of the database, and checks if the user has permission to read the root of the database. Since in your first rules **nobody** has read access at the root, the read operation is rejected.

---

Instead of reading the root of the database, and then only using the `settings` child of the snapshot, you should only read the `settings` node from the database:

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()        
database.reference("settings").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    //             read only this node
    object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val buildType = if (BuildConfig.IS_PROD) "prod" else "test"
            Timber.d("Database $snapshot")
            if (snapshot.child(buildType).exists()) {
                //  update this check to match
                val settings =
                    snapshot.child(buildType).getValue(Any::class.java)!!
                //  Also update this code
                val json = Gson().toJson(settings)
                val settingsDTO =
                    Gson().fromJson(json, FirebaseSettings::class.java)
                tasks.setResult(settingsDTO)
                Timber.d("Database 1 $settingsDTO")
                // database.reference.removeEventListener(this)
                //  This is not needed for addListenerForSingleValueEvent
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Timber.d("Database $error")
            tasks.setException(Exception(error.message))
        }
    })
```

---

While the above works, it actually reads more data than needed. Since your code only uses `/settings/$buildType`, you should read only that node.

So:

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()        
database.reference("settings").child(buildType).reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    //                                read only this node
    object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val buildType = if (BuildConfig.IS_PROD) "prod" else "test"
            Timber.d("Database $snapshot")
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                //  update this check to match
                val settings =
                    snapshot.getValue(Any::class.java)!!
                //  Also update this code
                val json = Gson().toJson(settings)
                val settingsDTO =
                    Gson().fromJson(json, FirebaseSettings::class.java)
                tasks.setResult(settingsDTO)
                Timber.d("Database 1 $settingsDTO")
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Timber.d("Database $error")
            tasks.setException(Exception(error.message))
        }
    })
```